# application gateway deployed using RM templates takes way too long

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I deploy a cluster with a simple application gateway using an RM template. The deployment stays for more than 30 minutes in deploying state with the appplication gateway being the bottleneck. It eventually succeeds. This is a very simple SSL gateway with a public IP.

Any clues on what might be going wrong or how to troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: This is a good question for Azure tech support. Someone from the product team might (hopefully) chime in here, but... technically speaking... it's not a programming question and this question will likely get closed.

Comment: Fair, I will cross-post at Azure MSDN forums as well.

Answer (score 4):

Same experience here. You are not doing anything wrong, it just takes some time (30 - 60 mins).

Comment: I can confirm this. It just takes time to spin up and configure the stack of required resources.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best is to vote for this if you want MS to work on it:

- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/19119910-application-gateway-management-operations-are-agon